# Add smooth animation when window grow

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

The idea I have is to give animation to a window/form when it grows. For example, the calculator of Windows 7 when it displays the unit converter or new features, the window changes size with smooth animation.
The problem is that I do not know which code to use when using a button to change the size (eg 200 pixels more).
I'm a beginner, so I do not know how to use "Timer" which was suggested to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this page, can be found whole concept (in C#). You can even download the code already done (again, in C#):
http://www.vcskicks.com/size-transform.php

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple implementation in C++/CLI. I used C++/CLI so I can play with the syntax. You can easily convert it to C#.

**AnimateWindowResize.h**

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO; // Stream
using namespace System::Drawing; // Bitmap
using namespace System::Reflection; // Assembly
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

public ref class AnimateWindowResize
{
private:
    static const int DEFAULT_STEP_AMOUNT = 15;

    bool m_startExpanding;
    bool m_animationEnabled;
    bool m_isHorizontal;
    Form^ m_windowsForm;
    Button^ m_initiateButton;
    int m_minSize;
    int m_maxSize;
    Timer^ m_timer;
    int m_stepRate;
    String^ m_initButtonText;
    String^ m_finalButtonText;
    String^ m_initButtonEmbeddedImageName;
    String^ m_finalButtonEmbeddedImageName;
    Bitmap^ m_initBitmap;
    Bitmap^ m_finalBitmap;


public: 
    AnimateWindowResize(Form^ windowsForm, Button^ initiateButton, bool isHorizontal, int minSize, int maxSize, bool isWindowExpanded);

    // init[final]EmbeddedImageName are images added under Linker -> Input -> Embed Managed Resource File.
    AnimateWindowResize(Form^ windowsForm, Button^ initiateButton, String^ initEmbeddedImageName, String^ finalEmbeddedImageName, String^ initButtonText, String^ finalButtonText, bool isHorizontal, int minSize, int maxSize, bool isWindowExpanded);

protected:

    void Init(Form^ windowsForm, Button^ initiateButton, String^ initEmbeddedImageName, String^ finalEmbeddedImageName, String^ initButtonText, String^ finalButtonText, bool isHorizontal, int minSize, int maxSize, bool isWindowExpanded)
    {
        m_initBitmap = nullptr;
        m_finalBitmap = nullptr;
        m_windowsForm = windowsForm;
        m_initiateButton = initiateButton;
        if (initButtonText != nullptr)
            m_initiateButton->Text = initButtonText;

        Stream^ stm = nullptr;
        if(initEmbeddedImageName != nullptr)
            stm = Assembly::GetEntryAssembly()->GetManifestResourceStream (initEmbeddedImageName);
        if (stm != nullptr)
        {
            m_initBitmap = gcnew Bitmap(stm);
            m_initiateButton->Image = m_initBitmap;
        }

        stm = nullptr;
        if(finalEmbeddedImageName != nullptr)
            stm = Assembly::GetEntryAssembly()->GetManifestResourceStream (finalEmbeddedImageName);
        if (stm != nullptr)
            m_finalBitmap = gcnew Bitmap(stm);

        m_minSize = minSize;
        m_maxSize = maxSize;
        m_startExpanding = isWindowExpanded;
        m_isHorizontal = isHorizontal;
        m_initButtonText = initButtonText;
        m_finalButtonText = finalButtonText;
        m_initButtonEmbeddedImageName = initEmbeddedImageName;
        m_finalButtonEmbeddedImageName = finalEmbeddedImageName;

        m_animationEnabled = true;
        m_stepRate = DEFAULT_STEP_AMOUNT;

        // Calculate the step rate
        m_stepRate = (int)((maxSize - minSize) / 10.0);
        if (m_stepRate <= 0)
            m_stepRate = DEFAULT_STEP_AMOUNT;

        m_timer = gcnew Timer();
        m_timer->Interval = 1;
        m_timer->Enabled = false;
        m_timer->Tick += gcnew EventHandler(this, &AnimateWindowResize::m_timer_Tick);
    }

    void m_timer_Tick(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
    {
        if (m_startExpanding)
        {
            if (m_isHorizontal)
            {
                if (m_windowsForm->Width >= m_maxSize)
                {
                    m_timer->Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    int tempWidth = m_windowsForm->Width + m_stepRate;

                    if (tempWidth >= m_maxSize)
                    {
                        m_windowsForm->Width = m_maxSize;
                        m_timer->Enabled = false;
                        return;
                    }

                    m_windowsForm->Width += m_stepRate;
                }
            }
            else // Vertical
            {
                if (m_windowsForm->Height >= m_maxSize)
                {
                    m_timer->Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    int tempHeight = m_windowsForm->Height + m_stepRate;

                    if (tempHeight >= m_maxSize)
                    {
                        m_windowsForm->Height = m_maxSize;
                        m_timer->Enabled = false;
                        return;
                    }

                    m_windowsForm->Height += m_stepRate;
                }
            }
        }
        else // Collaspe
        {
            if (m_isHorizontal)
            {
                if (m_windowsForm->Width <= m_minSize)
                {
                    m_timer->Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    int tempWidth = m_windowsForm->Width - m_stepRate;

                    if (tempWidth <= m_minSize)
                    {
                        m_windowsForm->Width = m_minSize;
                        m_timer->Enabled = false;
                        return;
                    }

                    m_windowsForm->Width -= m_stepRate;
                }
            }
            else // Vertical
            {
                if (m_windowsForm->Height <= m_minSize)
                {
                    m_timer->Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    int tempHeight = m_windowsForm->Height - m_stepRate;

                    if (tempHeight <= m_minSize)
                    {
                        m_windowsForm->Height = m_minSize;
                        m_timer->Enabled = false;
                        return;
                    }

                    m_windowsForm->Height -= m_stepRate;
                }
            }
        }
    }

public: 
    void StartAnimation()
    {
        m_timer->Enabled = m_animationEnabled;
        m_startExpanding = !m_startExpanding;

        // Change the text of the initiate button.
        if (m_startExpanding)
        {
            m_initiateButton->Text = m_finalButtonText == nullptr ? "Less" : m_finalButtonText;
            if (m_finalBitmap != nullptr)
                m_initiateButton->Image = m_finalBitmap;
        }
        else
        {
            m_initiateButton->Text = m_initButtonText == nullptr ? "More" : m_initButtonText;
            if (m_initBitmap != nullptr)
                m_initiateButton->Image = m_initBitmap;
        }


        if (!m_animationEnabled)
            ResizeWithNoAnimation();
    }

public: 
    property bool AnimationEnabled
    {
        bool get() { return m_animationEnabled; }
        void set(bool value) 
        { 
            m_animationEnabled = value;
        }
    }

private: 
    void ResizeWithNoAnimation()
    {
        // Just resize the window.
        if (m_startExpanding)
        {
            if (m_isHorizontal)
                m_windowsForm->Width = m_maxSize;
            else
                m_windowsForm->Height = m_maxSize;
        }
        else
        {
            if (m_isHorizontal)
                m_windowsForm->Width = m_minSize;
            else
                m_windowsForm->Height = m_minSize;
        }
    }
};
```

**AnimateWindowResize.cpp**

```
#include "AnimateWindowResize.h"

AnimateWindowResize::AnimateWindowResize(Form^ windowsForm, Button^ initiateButton, bool isHorizontal, int minSize, int maxSize, bool isWindowExpanded)
{
    Init(windowsForm, initiateButton, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, isHorizontal, minSize, maxSize, isWindowExpanded);
}

// init[final]EmbeddedImageName are images added under Linker -> Input -> Embed Managed Resource File.
AnimateWindowResize::AnimateWindowResize(Form^ windowsForm, Button^ initiateButton, String^ initEmbeddedImageName, String^ finalEmbeddedImageName, String^ initButtonText, String^ finalButtonText, bool isHorizontal, int minSize, int maxSize, bool isWindowExpanded)
{
    Init(windowsForm, initiateButton, initEmbeddedImageName, finalEmbeddedImageName, initButtonText, finalButtonText, isHorizontal, minSize, maxSize, isWindowExpanded);
}
```